# How do you pass data from one child component to another sibling?

Tags: reactjs

My goal is to display different values in the < h1 > of the GoalsDone component depending on which TeamCard is being hovered over. Both of these components are rendered inside of the TopGroups component, in these code snippets I am attempting to pass through the parent TopGroups.

Child component displaying the number of goals done:

```html
const GoalsDone = ({displayGoals}) => {
    return (
        <GameifyStyle className="">
            <Col className="GPM">
                <img className="pt-3 mx-auto pl-0" src="../images/bullseye.png" />
                <h1 className="pt-1"> {displayGoals}75 Goals</h1>
                <p>DONE</p>
            </Col>
        </GameifyStyle>
    )
}
```

Child Component that updates the score after being hovered over:
It currently has an unhandled runtime error "setDisplayGoals is not a function"

```html
const TeamCard = ({data}, {setDisplayGoals}) => {
    return (
        <TeamCardStyle>
            {!data && (
                <Spinner />
            )}
            {data && data.getGroupScores && (
                data.getGroupScores.slice(0, 4).map((group, index) => {
                    return (
                <Row onMouseEnter={() => {setDisplayGoals(group.totalScore)}}>
                    <Col className="teamCard mt-2 mb-2">
                        <Row>
                            <p>{seed[index]}</p>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                        <Col className="hideSmall">
                            <img className="mouseOn" src="../images/group.png" />
                            <img className="mouseOff" src="../images/groupSelected.png" />
                        </Col>
                        </Row>
                    <p>{group.name}</p>                            
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                    )
                })
            )}    
        </TeamCardStyle>
    )
}
```

Parent component:
ATTN lines 38, 48

```html
const GET_GROUP_SCORES = gql`
    query GET_GROUP_SCORES($quarter: String, $groupId: String) {
        getGroupScores(quarter: $quarter, groupId: $groupId) {
            name
            id
            totalScore
            goalsDone
            milestonesDone
        }
    }
`;


const TopGroups = () => {
    const {loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_GROUP_SCORES, {variables: { quarter: "Q2 2021" }})
    if (data) {
        const sortedGroups = data.getGroupScores.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.totalScore > b.totalScore) {
              return -1
            }
            if (a.totalScore < b.totalScore) {
              return 1
            } else {
              return 0
            }
           })
        }
    if (error) {
        return <p>An error has occured</p>
    }
    if (loading) {
        <Spinner />
    }
    const [displayGoals, setDisplayGoals] = useState('0');
    return (
        <Col className="col-12">
            <TeamCardStyle>
                    <Row>
                        <TeamCard 
                        data={data}
                        setDisplayGoals={setDisplayGoals}
                        />
                    </Row>
            </TeamCardStyle>
                <GameifyStyle>
                    <Row className="cardContainer mt-3 XsWidthAdjust">
                        <Col className="SideBorder TopGroupsFonts mx-1">
                            <GoalsDone
                            displayGoals={displayGoals} />
                        </Col>
                        <Col className="SideBorder TopGroupsFonts mx-1">
                            <PrizesWon />
                        </Col>
                        <Col className="SideBorderPH TopGroupsFonts mx-1">
                            <MilestonesOnTrack />
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </GameifyStyle>
        </Col>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "Child Component that updates the score after being hovered over: It currently has an unhandled runtime error "setDisplayGoals is not a function"" happens because you are destructuring the props wrong in your TeamCard component. Instead of doing

```
const TeamCard = ({data}, {setDisplayGoals}) => {
```

You should do:

```
const TeamCard = ({data, setDisplayGoals}) => {
```